# Call another Store Procedure from select statement query in a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am very new to MYSQL and Store Procedure. I am trying to find out a way if I can call a store procedure inside of a loop by fetching data from a table in a Store Procedure. Here are the example code for better understanding.

```
`CREATE TABLE `students` ( 
    `student_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `name` INT(11) NOT NULL,        
    `age` INT(11) NOT NULL,    
    `school` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)

)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

 CREATE TABLE `marks` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `student_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `subject` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `marks` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `grade` DATE NOT NULL,    

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Procedure

```
BEGIN

DECLARE if_finish INT(1) DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE cur_c INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE s_sub VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE s_mark INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE s_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    a.student_id,a.marks,a.subject
    FROM 
        markstable a 
        INNER JOIN studentstable b ON a.student_id =  b.student_id 
    WHERE 
        a.s_id> 0;        
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET if_finish = 1;

OPEN curs;
  SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO cur_c; 
  IF cur_c>0 THEN
  FETCH cur INTO s_id ,s_mark,s_sub;   
   call sp_calculatemarks(s_id,s_mark,s_sub);
  ELSE
    SET s_sub = '';
END IF;
CLOSE cur;



END
```

The above code is mostly running ok but the problem is its processing only one record whereas I have 48 Records in Marks table. But I don't know how to fetch all data in SP and call each by each to another Procedure. I think Cursor doesn't work in that way. Is there any concept like fetchrow?

I need some help with this method.

Comment: You aren't looping through the cursor.and I doubt if checking found_rows is the correct way to check if you have stuff to do. More normally I would check the value of the variable set by the handler see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html which gives you an example of how to do this

Comment: Thank You very much for the comment. I think the issue is solved. I will let you know.